# ipyvuetify: The resource “(localhost).../extension.js?v=...” was blocked due to MIME type (“text/html”) mismatch (X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff)

Tags: jupyter-widget, ipyvuetify

I am getting this error/warning on the browser
(e.g. Use Firefox, and right-click "inspect element")
from both jupyter and voila when trying to run any
ipyvuetify.VuetifyTemplate / vue.VueTemplate objects,

It does not stop the widget from running, but may be related to a bunch of more complicated bugs I try to solve....Any ideas on what is going on / why this happens / how to solve it?

Here is a minimal example:

```
import ipyvuetify as v
import traitlets

class Example(v.VuetifyTemplate):
    template = traitlets.Unicode('''
<template>
    <v-btn>
        FOOBAR
    </v-btn>    
</template>
    ''').tag(sync=True)
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

Example()
```

[image]